# Access XML Import: Issue with nested nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to import an XML file with an xsl to transform the file for a while with no success. 
Here is a sample of the XML data:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <Catalog>
  <Category1>
   <Name>Category1</Name>
   <Site>
     <Id>IDOfCategory1</Id>
     <Title><[Title]></Title>
   </Site>
   <SubCategory1>
   <Name>SubCategory1Category1</Name>
   <Site>
     <Id>IDSubCat1Cat1</Id>
     <Title><![Title]></Title>
   </Site>
   </SubCategory1>
   <SubCategory2>
   <Name>SubCategory2Category1</Name>
   <Site>
     <Id>IDSubCat2Cat1</Id>
     <Title><![Title]></Title>
   </Site>
   </SubCategory2>
 </Category1>
 <Category2>
  <Name>Category2</Name>
 <Site>
  <Id>IDOfCategory2</Id>
  <Title><[Title]></Title>
  </Site>
 <SubCategory1>
  <Name>SubCategory1Category2</Name>
  <Site>
    <Id>IDSubCat1Cat2</Id>
    <Title><![Title]></Title>
   </Site>
 </SubCategory1>
 <SubCategory2>
  <Name>SubCategory2Category2</Name>
  <Site>
    <Id>IDSubCat2Cat2</Id>
    <Title><![Title]></Title>
   </Site>
 </SubCategory2>
 </Category2>
 </Catalog>
```

What I need is this:

```
Category  SubCategory
---------  --------  
Category1 SubCategory1OfCategory1
Category1 SubCategory2OfCategory1  
Category2 SubCategory1OfCategory2                                  
Category2 SubCategory2OfCategory2
```

I tried several ways, the closest one was this one, but it's putting all Category1 in the first column and never change to Category2.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SubCategory">
<SubCategory>
        <Category><xsl:value-of select="../../Category/Name"/></Category>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</SubCategory>        
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I read some other solutions about this topic, that is how I reached this closest solution, but not far..I've been trying for several hours (two days...) and I am close to quit, so, any help will be appreciate.
Thank you!

I made this today:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="dataroot">
<html>
<body>
<table>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Catalog"/>
</table>
</body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalog">
<Categories>

<Category>
<xsl:value-of select="Category/Name"/>
</Category>

<SubCategory>
<xsl:value-of select="Category/SubCategory/Name"/>
</SubCategory>
</Categories>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This put only the first Category and the first SubCategory, nothing more than that.
I also tried the xsl:for-each before Categories, then after, then inside Category only, but it is not working...

Comment: Your xml is no valid. e.g. `<[Title]>` is not allowed. This need to be `&lt;[Title]>`.

Comment: By *Access* in the title, do you mean MS Access, Microsoft Office's database management system? And if so, are you using its [ImportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823157.aspx) method to migrate into database tables?

Comment: You XSLT is creating an XML document (which I guess you then import into Access). Can you show the actual XML you are expecting in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Thks for your comments. Yes, I mean MS Access. The actual XML file its too large, this is a model.

Comment: Thks for your comments. Parfait, yes, it is MS Access. Im not using the method just the buttons in External Data in MS Access. TIm, the actual XML file its too large, this is a model I made for this question.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Please post the **exact** expected output, **as code**. And please fix the input XML example too. Are the elements really numbered? Your stylesheet attempts suggest they are not.